# Where is the syntax of Apple documentation explained? (Specifically swiftUI documentation)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Where is an explanation of the syntax of the Apple's software? For example, when I look up 'List' for SwiftUI (cmd-shift-0 in Xcode) I see, among other alternatives:

```
init<Data, ID, RowContent>(Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?, rowContent: (Data.Element)
-> RowContent)
```

Great! What do the angle brackets mean? What is the significance of "RowContent" vs "rowContent"? etc. What do I actually write to make a list? Where is an explanation of this syntax?

If this is industry standard (I don't think so) what standard? I don't need a totally noob explanation but I need something more to go on than I have.

Comment: Well, if you ask what *angle brackets mean* then you need to start from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**
If you go to Apple's documentation for `List`, there's a bit more information on the `init` function in your question.

Here it is formatted below to fit:

```
// List declaration
struct List<SelectionValue, Content>
  where 
     SelectionValue : Hashable, 
     Content : View
```

```
// init declaration
init<Data, ID, RowContent>(
  _ data: Data, 
  id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, 
  selection: Binding<SelectionValue?>?, 
  @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent
) where 
   Content == ForEach<Data, ID, HStack<RowContent>>, 
   Data : RandomAccessCollection, 
   ID : Hashable, 
   RowContent : View
```

It's a bit of a mouthful, I agree.

**2.**
Angle brackets are used for [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html). This is a big topic that you need to understand about the language to be able to proceed.

In a nutshell, a Generic is a placeholder for the eventual concrete type (`String`, `Int`, `HStack`, `Foo`, etc...) that will be used, which is defined by the user of this function.

The generic placeholder type can be **constrained** to conform to a specific protocol or inherit from a certain class. This is done with the `where` clause.

**3.**
So, one by one:

List has 2 placeholders: `SelectionValue` and `Content` (could have been named anything, like `<T, U>`):

```
struct List<SelectionValue, Content>
```

and these placeholders are constrained:

```
where
   SelectionValue : Hashable, 
   Content : View
```

They are constrained to conform to `Hashable` and to `View` respectively.

So, basically, whenever you see `Content` in its function definitions, it means it could be any implementation of `View`. Likewise for `SelectionValue`.

Moving on:

```
init<Data, ID, RowContent>
```

In addition to the placeholders that `List` declares, `init` is also generalized to around three additional placeholders: `Data`, `ID`, and `RowContent`, also constrained:

```
where 
   Content == ForEach<Data, ID, HStack<RowContent>>, 
   Data : RandomAccessCollection, 
   ID : Hashable, 
   RowContent : View
```

`Content`: has to be a `ForEach` (of a specific type). You actually shouldn't care about it, since `Content` isn't any of the parameter types of `init`

`Data`: any type conforming to `RandomAccessCollection`, e.g. `Array`

`ID`: any type conforming to `Hashable`

`RowContent`: Any type conforming to `View` - basically any View

**4.**
Now, for the parameters:

```
init<Data, ID, RowContent>(
  _ data: Data, 
  id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, 
  selection: Binding<SelectionValue?>?, 
  @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent
)
```

`_ data`: is an unlabeled parameter of type `Data`, which is (see above) something like an Array

`id`: is a `KeyPath` (also, a [topic of Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563) that you should learn), but in a nutshell, an expression pointing to a property of an object. In this case, the object is an element of the `Data` (e.g. an Array), and the property is any `ID` (aka a `Hashable`).

`selection`: is a `Binding`. [Read more](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) about bindings in SwiftUI, and more about [property wrappers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617) (a Binding is available via a [`@State` property wrapper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state)). But it basically enables you to pass your state variable to a view so that it could change it without owning the data. A binding goes hand-in-hand with a `@State` wrapped property, by accessing its projected value with a `$` prefix. See example below.

`rowContent`: is a closure that takes an element of said `Data` (e.g. an element of an Array) and returns a `RowContent` (aka some `View`). Don't worry about `@ViewBuilder` for now.

**5.**
Example:

```
let strArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
@State var selection: String? = 0

// ...

List(strArray, id: \.self, selection: $selection, rowContent: { str in
  return Text(str)
})
```

`strArray`: is an Array, so it satisfies the generic constrain of `Data`

`\.self`: a key path expression, pointing to self (a String, which conforms to Hashable). This is only safe when the array is static and doesn't contain duplicates.

`selection`: is bound to the state variable `selection`. `$selection` is a projected value of that variable, which SwiftUI conveniently made into a Binding type.

`rowContent`: is a closure over each element of the array and returns a `Text` view.

Comment: Such a great answer -- very educational! You must have spent a lot of time writing this. I wish I could give it more than one green check.